# Flutter Display Widget before Animation ready

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, flutter-animation

I'm building an application in Flutter. On the initialisation, it needs to display an animated Widget with multiple animated parts. When I open the app, while the animated Text are correctly displayed, the stars widget are not initialised yet and thus, aren't shown. I need to go to another page and then, when I come back, the widget is displayed correctly. How to make the display wait until all the widget are ready before displaying it ?

Here's the called widget's State class :

```
class _StarsBackgroundWidgetState extends State<StarsBackgroundWidgetFul> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  late AnimationController animControlStar;
  late Animation fadeAnimStar1, fadeAnimStar2, fadeAnimStar3, fadeAnimStar4, sizeAnimStar, rotateAnimStar;
  late List<Star> listStar;
  late int numStars;
  late Size screenSize;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.black,
          child: buildGroupStar()),
        //Dispose new widget
          Align(
              child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      child: DefaultTextStyle(
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 35.0,
                          ),
                          child: AnimatedTextKit(
                            totalRepeatCount: 1,
                            animatedTexts: [
                              TypewriterAnimatedText(
                                  widget.quote.quote,
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                            ],
                          )
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 24,),
                    DefaultTextStyle(
                            style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                          ),
                          child: AnimatedTextKit(
                            totalRepeatCount: 1,
                            animatedTexts: [
                              TypewriterAnimatedText(
                                  widget.quote.author,
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.end),
                            ],
                          )
                      ),
                  ])
          )
      ]);
}

  @override
  Future<bool> initState() async {
    super.initState();
    listStar = [];
    numStars = 37;
    screenSize = widget.screenSize;

    // Star
    animControlStar = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000));
    fadeAnimStar1 = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0)
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(
        parent: animControlStar, curve: const Interval(0.0, 0.5)));
    fadeAnimStar1.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    fadeAnimStar2 = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0)
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(
        parent: animControlStar, curve: const Interval(0.5, 1.0)));
    fadeAnimStar2.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    fadeAnimStar3 = Tween(begin: 1.0, end: 0.0)
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(
        parent: animControlStar, curve: const Interval(0.0, 0.5)));
    fadeAnimStar3.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    fadeAnimStar4 = Tween(begin: 1.0, end: 0.0)
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(
        parent: animControlStar, curve: const Interval(0.5, 1.0)));
    fadeAnimStar4.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    sizeAnimStar = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 5.0)
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(
        parent: animControlStar, curve: const Interval(0.0, 0.5)));
    sizeAnimStar.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    rotateAnimStar = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0)
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(
        parent: animControlStar, curve: const Interval(0.0, 0.5)));
    rotateAnimStar.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });

    animControlStar.addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        animControlStar.reverse();
      } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
        animControlStar.forward();
      }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < numStars; i++) {
      listStar.add(Star(
          left: Random().nextDouble() * screenSize.width,
          top: Random().nextDouble() * screenSize.height,
          extraSize: Random().nextDouble() * 2,
          angle: Random().nextDouble(),
          typeFade: Random().nextInt(4)));
    }
    animControlStar.forward();
    return true;
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    animControlStar.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  //Build the star widget
  Widget buildStar(double left, double top, double extraSize, double angle, int typeFade) {
    return Positioned(
      left: left,
      top: top,
      child: Container(
        alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
        width: 10.0,
        height: 10.0,
        child: Transform.rotate(
          angle: angle,
          child: Opacity(
            opacity: (typeFade == 1)
                ? fadeAnimStar1.value
                : (typeFade == 2) ? fadeAnimStar2.value : (typeFade == 3) ? fadeAnimStar3.value : fadeAnimStar4.value,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.star,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: sizeAnimStar.value + extraSize,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // Create list of stars
  Widget buildGroupStar() {
    List<Widget> list = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < numStars; i++) {
      list.add(
          buildStar(listStar[i].left, listStar[i].top, listStar[i].extraSize, listStar[i].angle, listStar[i].typeFade));
    }

    return Stack(
      children: list
    );
  }
}
```